# Why does FireFox not point http://%67oogle.com to http://google.com?

Tags: http, url

I have a HTML file *test.html*:

```
<a href="http://%67oogle.com">http://%67oogle.com</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.%67oogle.com">http://www.%67oogle.com</a>
```

The links are working in Chrome, IExplorer, Safari, and Opera ([http://%67oogle.com](http://google.com) points to http://google.com).

However, the links do not work on FireFox (v13.0.1).

Why does FireFox not point http://%67oogle.com to http://google.com?

Comment: It looks like a bug. You may want to report it. (bugzilla.mozilla.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid HTTP URI is one which conforms to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.2), the HTTP/1.1 standard. It says:

```
... For definitive information on
URL syntax and semantics, see "Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI):
Generic Syntax and Semantics," RFC 2396 [42] (which replaces RFCs
1738 [4] and RFC 1808 [11]). This specification adopts the
definitions of "URI-reference", "absoluteURI", "relativeURI", "port",
"host","abs_path", "rel_path", and "authority" from that
specification.
```

and

```
The "http" scheme is used to locate network resources via the HTTP
protocol. This section defines the scheme-specific syntax and
semantics for http URLs.

http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
```

If we delve into [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396), it defines `host` as:

```
  host          = hostname | IPv4address
  hostname      = *( domainlabel "." ) toplabel [ "." ]
  domainlabel   = alphanum | alphanum *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
  toplabel      = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
```

Let's also look at [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

> The reg-name syntax allows percent-encoded octets in order to
> represent non-ASCII registered names in a uniform way that is
> independent of the underlying name resolution technology.  Non-ASCII
> characters must first be encoded according to UTF-8 [STD63], and then
> each octet of the corresponding UTF-8 sequence must be percent-
> encoded to be represented as URI characters.  **URI producing
> applications must not use percent-encoding in host unless it is used
> to represent a UTF-8 character sequence.**

So Firefox is completely right to not to redirect you. `%67oogle.com` is an invalid host part for a URL.

Comment: Hmm, so Chrome, IExplorer, Safari, and Opera are all *against* RFC?